# Updating position of d3 generated circles with a timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and fairly new to javascript in general and have encountered an error I can't explain with my current knowledge...

I've generated 6 circles using a 2d array (success) and have created a function to call in a timer to increment the x and y position by 1 each call. Currently the code I have generates the 6 circles but the timer infinitely creates more circles of "NaN" instead of updating the positions of the initial 6. My code is below;

```
<body>
    <div id="svgDiv"></div>

    <script src="~/scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/App/test.js"></script>

</body>
```

and js;

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowLength = window.innerHeight;

var pos =
    [[50, 40],
    [100, 80],
    [150, 120],
    [200, 160],
    [250, 200],
    [300, 240]];

var base = d3.select("#svgDiv").append("svg")
  .attr("width", windowWidth)
  .attr("height", windowLength);

function initSetup() {

    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;;
    windowLength = window.innerHeight;

    base.attr("width", windowWidth)
        .attr("height", windowLength);

    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
window.onload = initSetup;

function windowResize() {

    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;;
    windowLength = window.innerHeight;
    base.attr("width", windowWidth)
       .attr("height", windowLength);

};
window.addEventListener("resize", windowResize);

function svgDivClick() {

    base.selectAll("circle")
        .data(pos) // .data(pos, function (d) { return d; })
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return pos[i][0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
            return pos[i][1];
        })
        .attr("r", 0)
        .style("fill", "00ACCD")
        .transition()
        .attr("r", 20)
        .style("fill", "00ACCD")
        .duration(500);

    base.exit().transition()
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();

    console.log("click works");
    d3.timer(animate);
};
document.getElementById("svgDiv").addEventListener("click", svgDivClick);

function animate() {

    base.selectAll("circle")
        .data("circle", function (d) { return d; })
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return d.cx + 1;
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
            return d.cy + 1;
    });

    base.exit().transition()
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();
};
```

The end goal is to have the circles float about randomly but at this point I'm just trying to control the positions. EDIT: The error occurs in the animate function.

Any insights would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: What does a `console.log(d.cx)` reveal inside the function assigning to the attribute `cx`?

Comment: 6x Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN". the line itself undefined.

Comment: Update: the data I was passing in was the string "circle", rather than the circles, when I instead pass in my 2d array "pos" no errors are thrown and nothing logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems here. The main one is that you are binding the same data to the DOM elements 60 times a second, which makes no sense. The second one is that you are not *increasing* the positions, but simply resetting them. A third one is that there is no `cx` or `cy` properties in the data. A last one is that you are not declaring your circles' selection.

I made a simple demo to show you how to use a `d3.timer`. Check how the position is retrieved and changed. Also, have in mind that in this example I removed *all* transitions: mixing transitions and timers is complicated and, often, unnecessary.

Here is the demo:

```js
var windowWidth = 500;
var windowLength = 300;

var pos = [
  [50, 40],
  [100, 80],
  [150, 120],
  [200, 160],
  [250, 200],
  [300, 240]
];

var base = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", windowWidth)
  .attr("height", windowLength);

var circles = base.selectAll("charlesDarwin")
  .data(pos)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return pos[i][0];
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return pos[i][1];
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "00ACCD");

var timer = d3.timer(animate);

function animate() {

  circles.attr("cx", function() {
    if (+d3.select(this).attr("cx") > 500) {
      timer.stop()
    }
    return +d3.select(this).attr("cx") + 1
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```